# Escaping quote, both " and '

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I am trying my best to work this out and it is driving me crazy, I am hoping that I can use either preg_replace or ereg_replace for this.

Basically I am putting out string of text which is taken from a news article, I am taking the first 100 characters rounded to the closest end of word, the problem occurs if a " or ' appears in the 100 characters string and no closing " or ' is present, this then causes my PHP code to fail. So I need to write some kind of replace code so that all " and ' will be replaced with \" and \' so they are escaped and don't affect my PHP.

---

#### Update

I cannot correct anything to do with database insertion as I am dealing with a very old archive of data which I cannot process and re-enter into the database so I'm stuck with what I have got there.

This is the code I have:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '',substr($text, 0, 100));

echo '<div style="color: #8197cd;" >'.$text.'...</div>';
```

So that takes my text, shortens it and puts it to the nearest word.

Then I am trying to do something along the lines of:

```
$text = preg_replace("\"","\"",$text);
$text = preg_replace("\'","\'",$text);
```

But preg_replace is not a strong point of mine so that is completely wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something seems to be missing from your question.  You should consider posting the code that is having a problem.

Having quotes inside a variable you are echoing out is not going to fail.  The only thing I could imagine causing an error would be if you were using some sort of template system or code that was taking the string and using it to do an eval() somewhere, but that would be a very poor system.

If you are inserting the string into a database, then you would need to escape those characters, as mentioned by SiteSafeNL.

If an eval is the source of the problem, then htmlentities which he also suggested would fix it.

*Added based on latest additions to the question*

Please try this:

```
echo '<div style="color: #8197cd;" >'. htmlentities($text) . '...</div>';
```

And the preg_replaces are not useful, so simply omit that code.

Comment: Hi gview, I am not using an eval() or anything similar. the 1st 2 lines of code that I posted above are all that I am running and what is causing the problem. The way I can tell it is causing a problem is because it is showing my CSS divs out. Thinking about it maybe an unclosed '<' could be causing the problem? in which case how could I fix that?

Comment: @AdriftUniform: am i right in interpreting this to mean that you are not encountering a php error, but rather a malformed html error?  The answer in that case is to simply use htmlentities as originally suggested and there is no need for you to be trying to escape quotes, which won't work anyways in this context.  I'll amend my answer with a quick example.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will be giving this a try, I think if I was to use the strip_tags function that would solve my issue, considering I am only showing a short snippet of the article things like HTML links don't really need to be included

Answer (score 1):

> the problem occurs if a " or ' appears in the 100 characters string and no closing " or ' is present, this then causes my PHP code to fail.

You're trying to fix a problem that shouldn't be there in the first place - most likely unescaped input in a mySQL query. You need to fix that instead  (it's also a security problem).

Show the code that breaks, I'm sure someone will be able to point out what needs to be done.

Answer (score -2):

Don't you need anything like [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities)?

Comment: No idea why this has been downvoted, but the `escape` part is for inserting it into the database, and the entities are for the output...

Comment: @gview: It is not your job to "undo" other people's votes, or to remove other people's right to vote. Upvote only when you would have done so anyway. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a complete answer by any stretch.

Comment: @Tomalak: it is not my job to answer questions on stackoverflow either.  There was no reason for his answer to be downvoted, given the information he had to work with, and as I referred to it in my answer I felt it deserved consideration, plain and simple.

Comment: @gview: I repeat, you upvote when you think an answer is amazing. You do not vote to influence the final outcome if you would not otherwise have voted. If you upvote purely because you disagree with a total score of -1, to "make it even", then that is serially _offensive_. I think in many countries that's called fraud, and in some it is a capital offence. Just think about that.

Comment: @Tomalak:  I try and follow the rules of whatever online community I am in.  I already explained why I upvoted it.  It's also probably the correct answer.

Comment: @gview: [It's incomplete, for a start.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @Tomalak: did you happen to read the original question?  It did not provide near enough information for anyone to answer it.  Even the additional information provided really doesn't help.  Everyone is guessing.  Pekka's answer is just as much a guess as was mine.  If we get right down to it, Pekka's answer is most probably completely incorrect as escaping is needed for inserting into the db, not for echoing out a variable, but you didn't seem to have any problem with it.  Why are you picking on this other answer?

Comment: @gview: If you remember, I was picking on your "fixed the downvote" originally. The conversation -- w.r.t. _this_ answer -- has since evolved. We're getting quite far off-topic now, though.